# trouble with glib while installing Midnight Commander on centOS

Tags: centos, glib

I am trying to `./configure` midnight commander downloaded from http://ftp.midnight-commander.org/mc-4.8.14.tar.bz2
and I get the following:

```
checking for GLIB... no
configure: error: glib-2.0 not found or version too old (must be >= 2.14)
```

so I got a glib version from `ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/r/ra/ramonelinux/Rel_0.99/releases/i686/packages/glib-2.41.2-1.ram0.99.i686.rpm`

but when I install it, it clashes with the current version:

```
...
file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo from install of glib-2.41.2-1.ram0.99.i686 
conflicts with file from package glib2-2.40.0-4.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo from install of glib-2.41.2-1.ram0.99.i686 
conflicts with file from package glib2-2.40.0-4.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo from install of glib-2.41.2-1.ram0.99.i686 
conflicts with file from package glib2-2.40.0-4.el7.x86_64
```

Indeed, I have a valid glib installed:

```
sudo yum list installed | grep glib
ModemManager-glib.x86_64          1.1.0-6.git20130913.el7             @anaconda
NetworkManager-glib.x86_64        1:1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7 @base
dbus-glib.x86_64                  0.100-7.el7                         @anaconda
glib-networking.x86_64            2.40.0-1.el7                        @base
glib2.x86_64                      2.40.0-4.el7                        @base
glibc.x86_64                      2.17-78.el7                         @base
glibc-common.x86_64               2.17-78.el7                         @base
glibc-devel.x86_64                2.17-78.el7                         @base
glibc-headers.x86_64              2.17-78.el7                         @base
```

So why does MC give me bollocks about wrong glib version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the development package for `glib`:

```
yum install glib2-devel
```

You could save yourself the trouble of building Midnight Commander though, it's packaged for CentOS:

```
yum install mc
```